# The IMAP server replied to the 'SEARCH' command with a 'NO' response: Character set not supported for search

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I get this error when I use the search command with special charachter in searchPhrase like "سلام"
it works fine in other cases. I've also tried encoding to UTF-8. there is no error then but it doesn't give back any result.

```
var uids = Client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.SubjectContains(searchPhrase));
```

any suggestion?

Comment: i have this question too? what is solution?

Comment: The error message says the **SERVER** does not support the character set. It has nothing to do with your code. Talk to the people responsible for the server and ask them what character sets it supports.

Comment: Some servers have terrible internationalization support.

Comment: Mailkit does the right thing, it'll send either ENABLE at startup or a properly named CHARSET key. So it probably is the server. What server is this? And for that matter, what is the IMAP command sent on the wire?

Comment: Servers such as Exchange only seem to support us-ascii so if that's what his server is, he might be out of luck. Hopefully the IMAP server responded with a list of supported charsets and from that, maybe I can figure out a solution in MailKit.

Comment: the server is Gmail.but I didn't get what you meant by imap command sent on the wire?! SearchQuery.SubjectContains("سلام")

Comment: What he's asking for is what, in MailKit, is the [Protocol Log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog). It's just a *really* useful tool for debugging these kinds of client/server communication errors.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce any errors with GMail using your search query. MailKit seems to work fine. See my answer for a log of what MailKit sends and the server's reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this on GMail using MailKit and this is what I get:

```
S: A00000006 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)
C: A00000007 UID SEARCH RETURN () CHARSET UTF-8 SUBJECT {8+}
C: سلام
S: * ESEARCH (TAG "A00000007") UID
S: A00000007 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

What is the error? Seems to work fine for me (other than the fact that I obviously don't have any messages with that string in the Subject header).

Here is my little test program:

```
using System;

using MailKit.Net.Imap;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;

namespace GMailSearchTest {
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new ImapClient (new ProtocolLogger (Console.OpenStandardOutput ()))) {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;

                client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);

                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

                client.Authenticate ("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");

                client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.SubjectContains ("سلام"));

                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```